Besides Paul, were any saints complicit in the martyrdom of other saints?
According to Acts 8:1 and Acts 22:20, Saul participated in the martyrdom of Stephen, at least by granting approval to those who physically stoned him to death. Saul later underwent a conversion and became recognized (by the Roman Catholic Church and in Christendom generally) as a saint, St. Paul.
Are there any other saints recognized by the Catholic Church who had participated in the martyrdom of other saints recognized by the Catholic Church?

At the martyrdom of Stephen, Saul of Tarsus was not a believer in Christ, so could not be a 'Saint', either in the sense Catholicism understands that word, nor in the biblical sense of applying that title to all believers. It was only after Saul's later conversion to Christ that he became a believer in Christ, stopped killing and imprisoning Christians, and qualified for the designation of 'saint'. This means that the first two words in the question, "Besides Paul", should be removed - yes?

@Anne Your objection is like complaining that the statement "President Biden was born in 1942" is false because he wasn't yet president in 1942. The title was chosen to be concise, and any apparent ambiguity should be easy to resolve, particularly after reading the question.

Pardon me for being pedantic, but the way the question was worded suggested that a man called by Christ personally to minister to fellow Christians martyred fellow Christians. Anyone doing that can have their claim to be a Christian questioned. Paul's claim was always 100% legitimate. My comment is merely to honour the Apostle Paul.

Besides Paul, were any saints complicit in the martyrdom of other saints?
The short answer seems to be yes.
For example, one of the 40 Martyrs of Sebaste converted to the faith while guarding the 40 martyrs of Sebaste. When one abandoned his under torture, a Roman guard under inspiration of the Holy Spirit, declared himself to be a Christian and was martyred in the place of the one who renounced his faith.

The Forty Martyrs of Sebaste or the Holy Forty were a group of Roman soldiers in the Legio XII Fulminata (Armed with Lightning) whose martyrdom in the year 320 AD for the Christian faith is recounted in traditional martyrologies.
They were killed near the city of Sebaste, in Lesser Armenia (present-day Sivas in Turkey), victims of the persecutions of Licinius who, after 316, persecuted the Christians of the East. The earliest account of their existence and martyrdom is given by Bishop Basil of Caesarea (370–379) in a homily he delivered on their feast day. The Feast of the Forty Martyrs is thus older than Basil himself, who eulogised them only fifty or sixty years after their deaths.
Martyrdom
According to Basil, forty soldiers who had openly confessed themselves Christians were condemned by the prefect to be exposed naked upon a frozen pond near Sebaste on a bitterly cold night, that they might freeze to death. Among the confessors, one yielded and, leaving his companions, sought the warm baths near the lake which had been prepared for any who might prove inconstant. Upon immersion into the cauldron, the one who yielded went into shock and immediately died. One of the guards, Aglaius, was set to keep watch over the martyrs and beheld at this moment a supernatural brilliancy overshadowing them. He at once proclaimed himself a Christian, threw off his garments, and joined the remaining thirty-nine. Thus the number of forty remained complete. At daybreak, the stiffened bodies of the confessors, which still showed signs of life, were burned and the ashes cast into a river. Christians, however, collected the precious remains, and the relics were distributed throughout many cities. Veneration of the Forty Martyrs became widespread.

Other cases exist throughout the history of the Christendom.
